# Where do i add permissions for the _vti_bin folder?

Tags: 2010, wcf

When I try to use my custom WCF REST service I get authentication login prompt,

```
http://ServeName/_vti_bin/MyService/MyService.svc
```

So the question is, where do I need to add permissions, maybe in Central Admin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, I added Site permissions and it worked.